# jhipster Using docker image all tests failing

Tags: jhipster

For my project, I need to have a certain jhipster version.
But I also want to play around with all the new jhipster features (version 5+).
Therefore, my idea is to run the newest jhipster inside a docker container, so nothing intereferes with my project setup.

I followed [the offical jhipster install guide](https://www.jhipster.tech/installation/).
The installation was succesful.
Now comes there part where I am stuck.
Using `./gradlew test`, all tests fail.
I tried the `./gradlwe test` in both directories, meaning once in the docker container directory (`docker container exec -it jhipster bash` --> then inside the app folder doing `yarn install` and then `./gradlew test`)
and from my local directory where the volume got mounted (`~/jhipster`).
What am I missing?

For anyone interested in seeing the tests failing (this is how all of them look like):

> Task :test

```
org.jhipster.health.web.rest.LogsResourceIntTest > changeLogs FAILED
    java.lang.IllegalStateException
        Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException
            Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException
                Caused by: io.jsonwebtoken.security.WeakKeyException

org.jhipster.health.web.rest.LogsResourceIntTest > getAllLogs FAILED
    java.lang.IllegalStateException
        Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException
            Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException
                Caused by: io.jsonwebtoken.security.WeakKeyException

org.jhipster.health.web.rest.LogsResourceIntTest > testLogstashAppender FAILED
    java.lang.IllegalStateException
        Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException
            Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException
                Caused by: io.jsonwebtoken.security.WeakKeyException

org.jhipster.health.web.rest.AccountResourceIntTest > testSaveInvalidEmail FAILED
    java.lang.IllegalStateException
        Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException
            Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException
                Caused by: io.jsonwebtoken.security.WeakKeyException


137 tests completed, 113 failed

> Task :test FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
```

Comment: Looks like the issue is that your JWT secret base64 encoded is not long enough (WeakKeyException). It's either configured in application*.yml or in an environment var. See https://www.jhipster.tech/security/#jwt

Comment: That is what the exception tells me, but it makes no sense to me why this happens with a default jhipster config. See my "answer" for further confusion

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue, even though I do not understand HOW this is a fix.
Since I have a working `.yo-rc.json` I used `docker cp` to copy this file into the docker container and then ran `jhipster`.
Now I removed that file and ran a blank `jhipster` with the same configuration parameters and after this all `gradlew test`  did pass.